# Angular - Refresh or Re Subscribe service when route gets changed

Tags: angular

I have one component in my application in which products get called through service. I Call this service through a function on click method. When I click I pass a parameter to get a certain category. Now my problem is when I change my route, the list is not getting refreshed.

Service.ts

```
getProducts(service): Observable<Product[]>{
    return this.db.list("/products/" + service)
}
```

products.ts (component)

```
Products: Product[] = [];
filteredProducts: Product[] = [];
urlArea : string;
urlService: string;

constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private ProductService: ProductsService) {
      this.urlArea = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('area');
      this.urlService = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('service');
  }
private populateProducts(){
    this.ProductService
    .getProducts(this.urlService)
    .subscribe(Products => {
      this.filteredProducts = Products; // all listings will be stored in this
      this.Products = Products;
    });
}
```

I pass a parameter to service through route parameter. It works fine but when the route gets to change it doesn't refresh the list. I need to refresh the page to view the updated list.

Comment: If my answer solves your problem, do accept it.

Comment: @YashwardhanPauranik no. I have put my comments on your answer. Please check and help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `.subscribe()` to the `this.route.paramMap` in the `ngOnInit()` lifecycle method instead of getting its snapshot in the constructor.

As the `constructor()` will only run once the component is being registered. Whereas the `ngOnInit()` will fire every time component being re-initialized.

You can also, look into this [article](https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-router-route-parameters/) for better understanding

**NOTE:- You need to call the `getProducts` inside the subscription block of `route.paramsMap()`**

Comment: Yes. I have called populateProducts() function in ngOnIt() strill its not working for me

Comment: @SUN Can you post a working https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s6tsxf

Answer (score 1):

#### This is an issue with `getProducts` returning an `Observable`

`Observables` only emit values when instructed to, and this value can only be read by active `subscribers.` `Observables` do not hold their last emitted value, so any `subscribers` that did not read the last emitted value, or subscribed after the last emitted value will not get that value.

[More on Observables](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable)

#### This is where `BehaviorSubjects` come in

BehaviorSubjects are just like `Observables` except that they hold their last emitted value. *So any `subscribers` that did not read the last emitted value, or subscribed after the last emitted value will get that value when they subscribe.*

[More on BehaviorSubjects](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject)

Answer (score 0):

The constructor and the `ngOnInit` will only fire once when the component is first loaded. If the route changes but same component is displayed, it will not reload and neither of these methods will fire again. So if you call `getProducts` inside one of these methods, the data will not update when the route changes.

What you need to do is listen for route changes using the `params` observable on `ActivatedRoute`. Whenever the route changes, this observable will emit the new route params. Subscribe to this this observable, and whenever it emits use `switchMap` to trigger another `getProducts` call with the new param:

```
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {

  public products$: Observable<Product[]>;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private productSvc: ProductService){}

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.products$ = this.route.params  // this emits whenever the route changes
      .pipe(
        map(params => params.service),  // get the service id from the params object
        switchMap((service) => this.productSvc.getProducts(service)),  // re-fetch the data
      );
  }

}
```

But remember to subscribe to this observable otherwise nothing will happen!

You can do this explicitly by calling `this.products$.subscribe()` then saving the data to a particular prop in the callback. But it's better to use async | pipe to subscribe in the template as this will automatically unsubscribe when the component is destroyed. For example:

```
<div *ngFor="let product of (products$ | async)">
  {{product.id}}. {{product.name}}
</div>
```

I've put together an example in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/re-render-on-param-change). If you open up the console you can see that the `ngOnInit` only fires when the component is first loaded on the page, but the `params` observable emits whenever the route changes.